# Can not convert Pytorch ml model to TorchScript Version

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, coremltools

I'm trying to convert `PyTorch ml model` into `TorchScript Version` and then convert it to `Core ML` using `coremltools`.

**While trying to convert `PyTorch ml model` into `TorchScript Version` my code below keep getting following error:** `Dictionary inputs to traced functions must have consistent type. Found Tensor and Tuple[Tuple[Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor], Tuple[Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor], Tuple[Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor], Tuple[Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor], Tuple[Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor], Tuple[Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor]]`

my code:

```
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("Seungjun/t5-small-finetuned-xsum")
model.eval()

decoder_input_ids = output
traced_model = torch.jit.trace(model, (inputs['input_ids'], inputs['attention_mask'], output))
out = traced_model(inputs['input_ids'])
```

But all three parameters for `torch.jit.trace` have same type like follow:

```
inputs['input_ids'].shape
torch.Size([1, 219])

inputs['attention_mask'].shape
torch.Size([1, 219])

output.shape
torch.Size([1, 23])
```

Does anyone know why this is happening or is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

One thing looks suspicious: The model was traced with 3 inputs (ids, mask and output), but the inference was called with only one input.

Comment: If we look at [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/8923#issuecomment-738811521), we can know that we should provide 3 parameters(input_ids, attention_mask, decoder_input_ids)

Comment: @Seungjun I thought the error was thrown from `traced_model(inputs['input_ids'])`. You mean it was from torch.jit.trace?

Comment: @Seungjun btw, I have no problem running the code snippet in the github comment. I'm using transformers.__version__ = '4.25.1' and torch.__version__ = '1.12.1'

Comment: Yes that error happens at torch.jit.trace.

Comment: found out that problem was that I loaded ml model in wrong way. I should have added torchscript = True parameter like this: model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("Seungjun/t5-small-finetuned-xsum", torchscript = True)